# x86 assembly look for avg three number of three events

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86

I want to look for Prompt the user for the distances/heights for each of the three attempts for each of the three events and Average the scores for each event, and Multiply each event average by its factor to obtain a weighted score. Sum the weighted scores for a total final score. Display, to the user, each event name and their score for that event (weighted score), plus their final score, all in one window.

I know how to take the average and multiply, but I don't know how to type in these 9 Numbers, not conflict，and keep the output all in one window.
It is first part look for long jump avg or I only need repeat same code?

```
INCLUDE io.h           
    .586
.MODEL FLAT
.STACK 4096
.DATA
.CODE
number1     DWORD   ?
number2     DWORD   ?
number3     DWORD   ?
prompt1     BYTE    "Enter  long jump frist gardes", 0
prompt2     BYTE    "Enter  long jump second gardes", 0
prompt3     BYTE    "Enter  long jump third gardes", 0
string      BYTE    40 DUP (?)
resultLbl   BYTE    "The long jump avg is", 0
resultLb2   BYTE    "The high jump avg is", 0
resultLb3   BYTE    "The shot-put, avg is", 0
resultLb4   BYTE    "The final grade is", 0
sum1            BYTE    11 DUP (?), 0
sum2            BYTE    11 DUP (?), 0
sum3            BYTE    11 DUP (?), 0
total           BYTE    11 DUP (?), 0
.CODE
_MainProc PROC
        input   prompt1, string, 40     
        atod    string                  
        mov     number1, eax            
        input   prompt2, string, 40     
        atod    string
        mov     number2, eax
        input   prompt3, string, 40     
        atod    string
        mov     number3, eax
        mov     eax, number1            
        add     eax, number2            
        add     eax, number3            
        mul     eax, 7
        dtoa    sum, eax                
        output  resultLbl, sum1        
        mov     eax, 0                  
        ret
_MainProc ENDP
END
```

Comment: maybe add example, how your current screen looks, and what exactly you want to change about it? Also some quick summary of `atod`, `dtoa`, ... may help, as I have node idea from head, what they do. And why average is `(n1+n2+n3)*7` is mystery for me too, maybe some example with values. And I'm not sure about your second question, to avoid copy/paste code you have to avoid fixed pointers, like `dtoa sum,eax`, that should rather operate with pointer in register, so you can easily call the same code with different locations to be used for input/sum.

Comment: For each event, the athlete gets three attempts.  Each distance/height is recorded (in inches).  After the three attempts, the average is taken.
For the long jump, the average is then multiplied by a factor of 7.
For the high jump, the average is then multiplied by a factor of 4.
For the shot-put, the average is then multiplied by a factor of 5.
These values become the athlete's weighted scores for the events.
At the end of all events, the three weighted scores are added together for a total score. it is origin question for we need to do

Comment: that somewhat helps, but use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48811497/edit) link to put that rather into question, and mostly add some ascii art, how it looks *now*, and how it should look. I still don't exactly understand what is blocking you and what "9 numbers, not conflict" means, as for me it would be probably easy to do (not sure about those `dtoa`, if it is configurable enough), so I have no idea where you see a problem. And spellcheck your strings... it looks a bit lame to have so many typos. (I mean, it annoys asm programmers, because typos in code are very hard to find ;))